# Uno Platform Windows TextBox treats Tab key as Text instead of giving focus to next control

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, uno-platform, winui

I'm an absolute nebie in Uno Platform and did first steps to refresh my XAML knowledge.

Based on the default multiplatform Uno template I built a page where I bound a TextBox to a string property.

The TextBox behaves as expected on all platforms with rolling focus to the next control on Tab key but in then Windows app, the Tab key is treated as text input for the TextBox.

On a plain WinUI 3 app, the same XAML treats Tab key as expected and gives Focus to next control.

Is this a bug or can the behaviour be changed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Set `TabFocusNavigation="Cycle"` in your root container and then the **TAB** operation will cycle back to the first control instead of inserting a **TAB** as a text in your `TextBox` control.

For example:

```xml
<Grid
    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto"
    TabFocusNavigation="Cycle">
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```